# how to turn an array into a list

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to read each line in a file but it give an error every time I run it:

```
set fr [open temp.txt r]
set a [read $fr]
set b [split $a '\n']
foreach i $b{
*code*
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. There are no Tcl arrays in your code, but there is a Tcl list.

Comment: On top, the script provided is not operative (`fa` vs. `fr`, the order of execution is nonsensical). Provide an MVE.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This code works fine:

```
set fr [open input_file.txt r]
set a [read $fr]
close $fr
set b [split $a \n]
set fa [open temp.txt a]
foreach i $b {
   #Process items in list b
   puts $fa $i
}
close $fa
```

Comment: echo is not a Tcl command and you are splitting the input on newlines and single quotes.

Comment: Besides, the answer script does not resolve the issues of the original. What's about array vs. list? Besides: `puts $fa $i` within the loop? What about closing `$fa`? etc.

Comment: Thanks, code is updated. The answer resolves the question "I'm trying to read each line in a file but it give an error". The title "how to turn an array into a list in Tcl" seems to be unconnected to the question.

Comment: You are still splitting the input on single quotes, which is not what was asked. Either make it `split $a \n` or `split $a "\n"`.